# Amazon Route 53 - create A Record for ELB, create CNAME on another domain pointing to that A Record?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

One of the biggest shortcomings of AWS Elastic Load Balancer is the inability to assign a static IP to it. To get around this I have to use Amazon Route 53 DNS, which I can then set an A Record for the root/sub domain to point to the load balancer.

Let's say my Route 53 domain is:
domain1.com

I've create an elastic load balancer and pointed the following to it via A Record:
**sub.domain1.com**

I'm wondering, if I create a CNAME for another domain (such as sub.domain2.com) and point it to **sub.domain1.com** if this is OK?

Why do I need to do this?

We run promotional pages for clients websites by setting up static websites on subdomains of their sites. We currently give them a static IP for an EC2 instance which they then create an A Record for, but we're looking to do a load balanced cluster for high availability and scaling.

Has anyone tried this or know if this is OK to do? I know this concept is somewhat similar to S3 CNAME's but I just don't know if this bad or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One of the biggest shortcomings of AWS Elastic Load Balancer is the inability to assign a static IP to it.

That's not a design limitation, it's more of an indication that you're trying to use the ELB incorrectly.

> I'm wondering, if I create a CNAME for another domain (such as sub.domain2.com) and point it to sub.domain1.com if this is OK?

Yes, just make sure you set the TTL on CNAME low enough that if/when the IP addresses on the ELB change that your users aren't looking at stale records for too long.  Route53 uses 60 second TTLs.

> We run promotional pages for clients websites by setting up static websites on subdomains of their sites. We currently give them a static IP for an EC2 instance which they then create an A Record for, but we're looking to do a load balanced cluster for high availability and scaling.

If these are actually static websites, you'd be better off hosting them directly out of a S3 bucket.  Nothing important should ever be run on a single EC2 instance.

Comment: It is actually possible to use an ANAME record but these are quite rare and not many DNS providers provide it.

Comment: @jamieb I'm confused why you want to set such a low TTL on the CNAME.  This should only be required if replacing an elastic load balancer (something that should be extremely rare) which would require mapping the CNAME to a different A record, right?

Comment: @DerekLitz ELB's are just m1.small instances running a Java-based load balancing app.  Just like normal EC2 instances, they can fail or Amazon will retire the underlying hardware.  IP addresses can also change if they scale up/down or if there's an availability zone problem.

Comment: @jamieb Yes, which is why Amazon sets the DNS TTL for its load balancers at 60 seconds according to their documentation.  What doesn't make sense to me is setting the CNAME to such a low value. ie. www.nicedomain.com -> aws.load.balancer.domain.com -> (a set of IPs that can change often).  The fact that www.nicedomain.com is a CNAME for aws.load_balancer.domain.com does not need to be updated every 60 seconds, since the load balancer will rarely ever need to be replaced.  Replacing the load balancer would result in amazon generating a different domain name for the lb.